# Cross-browser SVG Textpath (Safari & Firefox)

Tags: firefox, svg, safari, cross-browser, snap.svg

Good afternoon,

I'm creating a SVG-based program and I'm having cross-browser problems with SVG textpath when opening with safari and mac-firefox. It works great with chrome, windows-firefox and IE.

take a look here:

http://codware.com/test.svg

screenshots:

Good:

http://codware.com/chrome-svg.png

Bad:

http://codware.com/mac-firefox-svg.png

http://codware.com/safari-svg.png

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The firefox issue was Fixed changing the initial PATH to a curve, it don't work with a rect path

The Safari issue remains, that can be checked here:
http://codware.com/logochrome/

1- Click at "Earth"
2- At sidebar click at "Curved Text"